# Invisible form fields in NSIS?

Tags: winforms, installation, nsis, nsdialogs

Is it possible to create invisible form fields in an NSIS installer?  I'm using nsDialogs and currently have a checkbox that toggles some fields from to readonly/non-readonly by using:

```
SendMessage $TextBox1 ${EM_SETREADONLY} 1 0
```

I'd like to make this control visible / not visible.  Is this possible?  How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ShowWindow $handle <0|1>

Comment: That will hide the window though... I just want to hide a textbox.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue and ended up setting a field to be off the page to make it 'invisible'. I am no expert, but it seems to work for me:

```
WriteIniStr $PLUGINSDIR\Directories.ini "Field 4" "Left"  "500"
WriteIniStr $PLUGINSDIR\Directories.ini "Field 4" "Right"  "500"
```

Of course you need to set it back to its original position to make it 'visible' again.